# payeazy payment method Access Denied issue

Tags: jquery

I am a web developer i have intergate  the payeezy payment gateway 
my testing site working correctly 
but 
on production site it give below error

```
 Payeezy.callback(            
                {"status": 401,
                  "results": {
                  "type": "FDToken",
                  "status": "failed",
                  "Error": {"messages": [{"code": "401","description":"Access Denied", "correlation_id":"232.9012433529443"}]}
              }})
```

the following link which i used to generate the toke my apikey and security_key are correct
https://api.payeezy.com/v1/securitytokens?apikey